# Html/Css dynamic centering

Tags: html, css

what I want to achieve is the following,
I have 6 divs in the bottom which are aligned horizontal and have the rest of the screen size as equal margin left and right.

Now when the screen's width is to small to display them in one row, I want to display them in two rows (with 3 divs each). All of this is working right now, but when it becomes a two row layout the equal margin left and right is gone and they clip at the left of the screen.

Am I missing something ?

```css
.container{
  z-index: 3;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.center-container{
  display: table;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.inner-container{
  display: inline-block;
}

.group-container{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.element{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #000000
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center-container">
      <div class="inner-container">
          <div class="group-container">
              <div class="element"></div>
              <div class="element"></div>
              <div class="element"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="group-container">
              <div class="element"></div>
              <div class="element"></div>
              <div class="element"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle example of working one row layout: https://jsfiddle.net/7ef7xLhu/

JsFiddle example of non working two row layout: https://jsfiddle.net/9oc19oky/

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can align them by setting `text-align: center;` to parent as they are `inline-block` elements by default they are align to the left.

```
.inner-container {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```css
.container {
  z-index: 3;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.center-container {
  display: table;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.inner-container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.group-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.element {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #000000
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="group-container">
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="group-container">
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You guys are the best <3

Answer (score 0):

Added `text-align: center;` to `.inner-container`

```css
.container {
  z-index: 3;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.center-container {
  display: table;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.inner-container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.group-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.element {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #000000
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="group-container">
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="group-container">
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
        <div class="element"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add *text-align: center* to the parent(inner-container). You should be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Just **add** this in your CSS and you are done. :)

```
.inner-container {
     text-align: center;
}
```

> You can refer to my link as well if you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/Dhruvil21_04/hadu5my3/